# how to prevent handling of a time based event by users

Tags: javascript, time, server, client

I'm actually working on a website that should host a sort of maths competitions. Every game has its own page and its own start and term.
Currently in every page I'm managing the time with a javascript function. Something like this:

```
var start = new Date(/*date of start*/),
    end = new Date(/*date of end*/);
function timeControl() {
    var now = new Date;
    if (now<start) {
        //case 1
    } else if (now>start && now<end) {
        //case 2
    } else {
        //case 3
    }
}
setInterval(timeControl, 1000);
```

My problem is that JS is run by client, so users potentially can handle the mechanism and simulating all possible cases in every moment.

The question is: how can I prevent the handling by users? Obviously I mean not in JS because I think in JS isn't possible...

Answer (score 0):

This is a super-broad questions, since how exactly it could be done depends on a lot of factors - which backend do you have, how well do you know it, what are exact requirements to what should happen in what case and so on.

But as a general idea, everything that is on a client side, can and will be manipulated by a client, no matter how well you do that, so your only hope is doing all this logic on a server.

In your case it might be something like this:

1. When showing a page with a contest to a client, record (on server side!) the timestamp you served it to him.
2. When client submits a solution, check (again, on server side!) difference between current timestamp and timestamp he was served the timestamp.
3. On client side you might add some logic to track & hide some content after allowed time expires, and it will work in 99% cases, but as you have already discovered, this will be tampered with and as such, you can regard it only as cosmetics to spice things up.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is the only way. What I meant with my question is: how can I practically do this?
I'm not an expert of developing and web-developing, I code just for hobby, but I am interested in learning new language and new areas of developing.
For example I had thought that ajax could have been a possible solution, but in the matter of facts it isn't because the response from server is treated with JS, so nothing will change...

Comment: Again, the question is super broad, I can't help you and I doubt anyone can. In situations this broad I always recommend this: take a pen and a paper, think real hard and try to envision what exactly is it you want to achieve. Exactly as in clearly, fully and unambigiously. Write down all of it and begin breaking down in smaller pieces.  Some of them you will know how to code, some of them you'll ask on SO. Also in process you might understand that you no longer want what you want now, which is an added bonus ;)